# Getting Table Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to get an element for a specific row in my HTML table.

Here is my table.

```
    <tr class="inner2-top">
    </tr>
```

I fill this table using Javascript for the following class:

```
    <td class="ddu-orl">
```

So far I have around 9 rows. I was wondering how I would get the data for a specific row.

So far I have the following  code but it seems to log all of the data for that class. What about for a specific row?

```
function removeRoute() { 
  var objectId = $(".inner2-top").find(".ddu-orl").text();
  console.log(objectId);
}
```

I run the following code using the following HTML:

```
<td class="status1"><img src="images/cross.png" href="#" onclick="removeRoute()" width="12" height="12" alt="cross">
```

Comment: The <td> element has class "ddu.orl", however, you are trying to select it with "ddu-orl"

Comment: Minor formatting error. Not the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within an `onclick` function if you pass `this` as argument it makes it easy to isolate instance.

```
<img  onclick="removeRoute(this)">
```

Now you can traverse the DOM from the image. One path is first look up to the closest row, then looking within that row for the element wanted

```
function removeRoute(elem) { 
  var objectId = $(elem).closest('tr').find(".ddu-orl").text();
  console.log(objectId);
}
```